# Scheduling Monthly job using oozie coordinator

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce, oozie

Can you please help me with, what can be used to for scheduling an oozie coordinator job to execute on first Monday of every month.

I know we have a frequency parameter that can be set as ${coord:months(1)} . But this will not allow me to schedule the jobs on a particular day of a particular week of a month. Hope I am not complicating the question here.

Any help is strongly appreciated.

Thanks,
Syed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unfortunately cannot schedule in the specific manner you are looking for. As you already note, you can run on a monthly basis - i.e. the 5th day of each month, but you are not be able to control the Day of the Week other than for the first materialization.

A possible work around this would be to run your coordinator on a weekly basis, to materialize on the Monday and then have a custom Java Action as your first step in the workflow that will throw an exception if it's not the first day of the month.

A downside of this approach is that you'll see 4 or so failures per month in the job list for the coordinator, but at least it will give you the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I was actually looking for something, what we already have in the cron expressions. But since this functionality is not supported by oozie. I will certainly have to go with what you have proposed here. Thanks for the help again.